# How to speed up printing selected cells to pdf file and saving xlsm file to shared device?

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-pdf

I've just written the MS Macro script in VBA which selects cells to print to pdf file and saves that pdf and xlsm Files in **shared device** (in this case i have Raspberry Pi). I when I select cells A1:X51 it prints that but it takes long. I've tried by adding that lines of codes:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
     Application.EnableEvents = False
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
```

But these didn't help. I have a question for now: Is it possible to speed up printing selected cells and saving pdf and xlsm files to shared device?

Thanks in advance.

**Macro code:**

```
Sub SaveFile()
'
' Macro Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Selection.Address
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="\\raspberrypi\Home_share\File.pdf", _
         Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
         IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
         IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
         OpenAfterPublish:=True
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = False
    End With
         Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
         Application.ScreenUpdating = False
         Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
         Application.EnableEvents = False
         Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

         ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "\\raspberrypi\Home_share\File-TV.xlsm"
         ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Does it perform better when created locally ? If yes: create it there and copy / move it afterwards

Comment: I know that something different working locally. But i have to export to pdf to shared device which is raspberry PI.

Comment: You are not answering the question: is it faster or not ? How are we supposed to improve your Raspberry SMB performance ? If this is the issue SO is the wrong place and you either have to tune your Windows or your Linux